# Script for copying an existing spreadsheet when a different spreadsheet is edited

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm very new to the Google Script world, and am trying to write a script so that when someone edits one of two columns in a spreadsheet, it causes a different spreadsheet to be copied and renamed based on the values of other columns in the row that is edited. The script I have so far is below and all of the logs work correctly, but I get an error related to the final copy function: "Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFolderById."

Right now, I have an installable trigger on the spreadsheet that's being edited. How to I get these permissions to work correctly? Any advice is greatly appreciated!

```
function CreateNewSheet(e) {//"e" receives the event object

  var col = e.range.getColumn();//Get column number of edited cell
  Logger.log(col)
  
  var row = e.range.getRow(); //Get row number number of edited cell
  Logger.log(row)
  
  if (col != 12 && col != 14) {return;}// Halt the code if the column is not one of 2 of interest
  Logger.log("in the function")
  
  var id = "1qg5ZZOifJ1l0V4N8Gxa3qhOBRiMwpyFawdUDny7IB-o"; //ID of other spreadsheet to be copied
  var initial = e.value; //value from current spreadsheet needed for rename
  Logger.log(initial)
  var num = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 1).getValue(); //value from current spreadsheet needed for rename
  var name = num + "_" + initial
  Logger.log(name)
  
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1DKpPbht1gGeKstXKMz6VtCz4TGj-4RJm")
  DriveApp.getFileById(id).makeCopy("name", destFolder);
};
```

Comment: You will need an installible trigger for that

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)` can not be ran if the trigger is simple. Use an installable trigger. You can either google/stackoverflow it or see the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) how to create an installable trigger.

Comment: Thank you both -- I've switched to an installable trigger, and now am getting a specific permission error on my final two lines (see edited code)

Comment: @MS delete the current trigger and create a new one so you will give access to DriveApp methods. If that worked, you may confirm the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation / Solution:**

Two things to note:

1. You need an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to use methods that require authorization. You updated the answer and you did that.
2. Regarding the second issue, I believe you created the installable trigger before you added the `DriveApp` lines in the bottom of your code. If that is true, then you haven't given permission to the script to access your drive.

Remove the current installable trigger and create a new one and I expect the new trigger will ask you to allow access to `DriveApp`.